# Y label misaligns axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I add a Y axis label, the axis generated by pgf plots is misaligned when I try to center it. This becomes more aparent when I have a table right before it. How can I center the axis without the Y axis "pushing" the graph to the right.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
bla bla & bla bla & bla bla & bla bla & bla bla \\ \midrule
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ylabel={something}
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not really misalign, the question is where you define the "anchor" for the alignment. I assume that you use (I'm your head) the y-axis as the anchor for the horizontal alignment.

Comment: +1: Nice MWE and visual explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={something},
]
\addplot{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[dashed] (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph horizontal aligned on page]

Comment: +1: Can you explain your approach a bit?